# jboss eap 6.4 in maven access failed

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, jboss

I had deploy maven project built in war package to Jboss EAP 6.4 and successfully, WAR package deployed. I had created services and run with spring-boot in local eclipse and I can ran in browser but I have a problem when access that URL based on war package in Jboss eap. I success ran jboss service but cannot run the URL. for example, I have service with method GET with url: localhost:8080/letter-printing-eap-generator/testing cannot run in jboss but ran in local eclipse before deploy. how to fix this problem? any configuration xml in maven project? I just add jboss plugin. thanks. my code:

my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.prudential.letter.printing</groupId>
    <artifactId>letter-printing-eap-generator</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>LetterPrintingEapGenerator</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>1.2.2.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
        <swagger.version>2.6.1</swagger.version>
        <jboss.home>${env.JBOSS_HOME}</jboss.home>
        <config.server>http://10.170.49.103/configserver</config.server>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- JBOSS maven plugin to simulate deployment to JBOSS -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.9.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jbossHome>${jboss.home}</jbossHome>
                    <serverArgs>
                        <serverArg>-Dspring.profiles.active=${run.profiles}</serverArg>
                        <serverArg>-Dspring.cloud.config.uri=${config.server}</serverArg>
                    </serverArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

SpringBootRestApiApp.java

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.prudential.letter.printing"})
@Import({SpringDataRestConfiguration.class})
public class SpringBootRestApiApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootRestApiApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class TestingController {

    @GetMapping("testing")
    public String getTestingMethod(){
        return "Hello Testing";
    }

    @GetMapping("data")
    public Map<String, Object> getData(){
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        map.put("status", "200");
        map.put("message", "ini messagenya");
        map.put("content", "mantap");

        return map;
    }
}
```

this is my project structure:

[image: project structure]

application.yml :

```
server:
  port: 8080
  contextPath: /letter-printing-eap-generator
```

Comment: What is the full name of the WAR file that maven builds?

Comment: letter-printing-eap-generator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war I created from command "mvn clean install"

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any specific configuration, JBoss EAP will provide access to your web application at a context with a name that matches the WAR file name.

Therefore, your application should be accessible at:

```
http://localhost:8080/letter-printing-eap-generator-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/testing
```

A common way of changing this for development purposes is to include a `finalName` element in the pom.xml file:

```
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        ...
    </build>
```

This will generate a WAR file named `letter-printing-eap-generator.war` and the original URL that you tried should work.

Alternatively, you could add a `jboss-web.xml` file to your deployment (in the WEB-INF directory) that contains a `context-root` element:

```
<jboss-web>
     <context-root>letter-printing-eap-generator</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

You could also do this using the JBoss CLI or the web console to perform deployment as well.

Comment: I had already add tag finalName in pom and access that url but still failed. must I use xml configuration jboss? do you have full configuration in jboss-web.xml and context-root? and where is the folder I put the xml file? thanks

Comment: If `finalName` is not working then something else is wrong. Do you have an index.html file at the root of your deployment?

Comment: no.. I not configure or add the xml file.. I just add the java file. I attach the structure project picture and I updated in my question. thanks.